# Get all Documents from one Collection that are not referenced from another collection

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I am trying to find all Documents from collection A that are not referenced from any document in collection B.

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39555871/572644), but I am unable to translate it to C#.

So far, I have tried this:

```
from a in docA.AsQueryable()
join b in docB.AsQueryable() on a.Id equals b.DocARef into bs
from sub_b in bs.DefaultIfEmpty()
where sub_b == null
select new { a.Id, a.Name };
```

and

```
from a in docA.AsQueryable()
join b in docB.AsQueryable() on a.Id equals b.DocARef into bs
from sub_b in bs.DefaultIfEmpty()
where !bs.Any()
select new { a.Id, a.Name };
```

Both result in a `NotSupportedException`: `$project or $group does not support {document}.`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the C# driver is not correctly following the conventions of LINQ here.

The correct query looks like this:

```
var result =
from a in docA.AsQueryable()
join b in docB.AsQueryable() on a.Id equals b.DocARef into bs
where !bs.Any()
select new { a.Id, a.Name };
```

Please note that there is no `DefaultIfEmpty` but the join still behaves like a left outer join.